# How to change Metallic Map Source

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to ask how can I change via code the following Metallic Map Source:

[image]

From Metallic Alpha to Albedo Alpha?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Material material = theObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().sharedMaterial;
material.SetInt("_SmoothnessTextureChannel", 1);
material.SetFloat("_Albedo", 0.5f);
```

You can set values whatever you want. If you want to change it to Metallic so replace `_Albedo` to `_Metallic`.